# Unable to delete the files given by Docker with mounted volume

Tags: python, docker

I am running a python script that downloads CSV file using some API with a docker run command.

I am using one Dockerfile to install all the OS level dependencies and requirements.

Once the build is created, I am using the following command :

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/Reports:/usr/src/app/Reports --rm ImgName python myScript.py -d 2015-11-25
```

As mentioned in the above command I have one directory named **Reports**.
I have mounted that directory with Docker.
The Script Executes successfully and downloads a CSV file but The Problem is, The Downloaded CSV file is in read-only mode. I am not able to delete it.
I need to have the flexibility to delete any file downloaded via script.

- Note: When I run the script without docker `i.e. python myScript.py` I can read, write and delete the file.*

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify, you can't access the files from outside the docker container? What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: you need to set the corect permissions on `$(pwd)/Reports` something like `775`

Comment: How can I do that? Can you please help me with full command?

Answer (score 1):

you can run docker with your own user with the following command:

```
docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) ...
```

This will make the container run as your user and all the files will be created with the right owner (see [docker run docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user)). Don't forget to delete the files you already have there or create a new folder for this

Comment: Not working !! 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.cache'

Comment: You probably left that file behind from the previous run. Can you run in a clean folder?